# generate file number in fixed 6 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, for-loop

I have a file conversion utility which extracts a page in a file and saves in the fixed 6 digit file name like:

```
000001.jpg  -  first page of file
000002.jpg  -  second page of file
...
000010.jpg  -  tenth page of file
000011.jpg  -  eleventh page of file
000100.jpg  -  hundredth page of file
000101.jpg  -  and so on...
...
001000.jpg
001001.jpg
...
...
999999.jpg  -  upto the maximum 999999th page. (6 digits max)
```

etc.

I mean the preceding 0 digits gets eliminated when file number reaches extra digit. The file name will always be 6 digits from `000001.jpg` to `999999.jpg`

Now, in my code I am trying to read all files. I am using a for loop with a counter from 1 to 999999 to read the file names. But when I use `File.Read("00000" + iCount + ".jpg");` it gives error when for loop counter is 10 because then it becomes 7 digits: `0000010.jpg` and the file name becomes invalid. And like it becomes 8 digits when the counter is 100.

How do I generate file names in my for loop in the valid manner?

Comment: Don't know C#, but could you just pad it with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx). `name.PadLeft(6, '0');` (`name` is `01`, `100`, etc.)

Comment: @pushkin thanks, I will try it now. I was missing the technique/keyword "padding" :) because I did not know what to search to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate such file names using the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    string newFilename = i.ToString("000000") + ".jpg";
}
```

Similarly for reading you can use `File.Read(iCount.ToString("000000") + ".jpg");`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string.Format("{0,6}",fileCount).Replace(' ','0')+".jpg";
```